# How to assign a variable value depending on a condition on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    number       type   username  product publishing_dt          genres  count
0        1     access   kerrigan      897    2019-03-05             VXA      0
1        1     access   kerrigan     1459    2008-05-06         VXA,VHS      0
2        1  orderline  45michael    76863    2019-10-04        VXA,B,GT      1
3        1  orderline  45michael    86833    2020-02-04          VS,KJM      1
4        1  orderline  45michael   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS      1
5        1  orderline    alicia7   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS      1
6        1  orderline     angel8    86217    2017-01-06           B,GTE      1
7        1  orderline      john5    86833    2020-02-04          VS,KJM      1
8        1  orderline      john5   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS      1
9        1  orderline   kerrigan    76863    2019-10-04        VXA,B,GT      1
10       1  orderline   kerrigan  1023897    2020-01-07          GT,VHS      1
11       1  orderline     kylemm   537077    2017-05-07          VXA,GT      1
12       1  orderline     uololo   830166    2019-12-05           VXA,B      1
13       3     access     7762hc    84325    2018-04-03  VHS,GT,GTE,VXA      0
14       4     access   adrian12   997165    2016-02-01            B,GT      0
15       4     access   kerrigan     5467    2020-01-24         VXA,VHS      0
16       4     access      yvera    76863    2019-10-04        VXA,GT,B      0
17       5     access   kerrigan   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS      0
18       6     access   kerrigan     2345    2020-02-01         VXA,VHS      0
19       7     access   kerrigan    78921    2019-11-03          GTE,BS      0
20       7     access   kerrigan    86833    2020-02-04          VS,KJM      0
21       8     access   kerrigan      645    2020-02-10         VXA,VHS      0
22      10     access  45michael    63767    2020-01-01        GT,B,VHS      0
```

Where *type* indicates the type of access the user has made to the product (if it was a **purchase** ('*orderline*') or if it was a **visit** ('*access*'), *product* is the unique identifier of the product in question, *number* is the number of times a user has accessed the product (*if type == access*) and *count* represent the number of times a user bought a product.

I want to change the *count* value so it goes **from 0 to 1**, where 0 would represent not bought and not purchased and 1 purchased, and the values between a proportion corresponding to the number of accesses, so it could be 0.9 for 20 or more times, 0.5 for 10 times and so on.

Any idea on how can I do this?

Expected output:

```
    number       type   username  product publishing_dt          genres  count
0        4     access   kerrigan      897    2019-03-05             VXA    0.2
1       10     access   kerrigan     1459    2008-05-06         VXA,VHS    0.5
2        1  orderline  45michael    76863    2019-10-04        VXA,B,GT    1.0
3        1  orderline  45michael    86833    2020-02-04          VS,KJM    1.0
4       15     access  45michael   130365    2020-02-10   VXA,GT,B,JFSS    0.8
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the formula for your count? `count = f(accesses) = ..`?

Comment: I want to go from 1 [purchased] and linearly go down to 0 [not purchased] through accesses, as I don't really know how to do this I didn't think of a function now, I was thinking of assigning 0.9 to 20 accesses and go down from there